# LineIterator in OpenCV C++ in Android

Tags: android, c++, opencv

I write a program which obtain value of color Asymmetric at lesion.
my program in visual studio Working correctly and I get color Asymmetric. But program in android (use Native) always return 0.
The problem is that points[j] always has same value therefor value of avg_i[i] with avg is equal.
my code:

```
Mat& srcMat = *(Mat*)src;
Mat& mask_tr = *(Mat*)Mask;

Mat gray;
cvtColor(srcMat, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);

double summation=0, avg=0, NCD=0, mismatch=0;
double* avg_i = new double[p.size()];
double* ncd = new double[p.size()];
double* XOR_Cs_Cl = new double[p.size()];
int A_x=0, A_t=0;
vector<Vec3b> buf;

for(int i=0; i<p.size(); i++){

    LineIterator it(gray, p5, p[i], 8);
    vector<Point> points(it.count);

    for(int j=0; j<it.count-1; j++)
    {
        buf.push_back( Vec3b(*it) );
        points[j] = it.pos();
        it=it++;

        summation += int(gray.at<uchar>(points[j].y , points[j].x));
    }

    avg_i[i] = summation / (it.count-1);
    summation = 0;
    avg += avg_i[i];
}

avg = avg/p.size();

for(int i=0; i<p.size(); i++){
    ncd[i] = avg_i[i] * (100/avg);
    A_t += ncd[i];
    XOR_Cs_Cl[i] = abs(100 - ncd[i]);
    A_x += XOR_Cs_Cl[i];
}

mismatch = (double(A_x) / double(A_t))*100;

delete [] avg_i;
delete [] ncd;

return mismatch;
```

Comment: re `Mat& srcMat = *(Mat*)src;`, starting the code example with possible UB and use of undefined identifier is quite clever.